# Any improvements in this code without using the outer function to filter even numbers?

Tags: python, decorator

I'm new to python and my niece asked me to create a function that takes 2 args. The return value is to filter even number from the range of that function result.

This is my resulting code:

```
def filter_even(N):
    if N%2==0:
        return N

def f_evendecorator(func):
    def get_even(*args):
        f_even = filter_even
        f = func(*args)
        even = []
        for number in range(1,f+1):
            if f_even(number)!=None:
                even.append(f_even(number))
        return even
    return get_even

@f_evendecorator
def mult(x,y):
    return x * y
```

Comment: Valid in what way?  Are you asking whether it compile (it will, provided you fix the case of the `n`) or are you asking whether it will do what you expect?  And if the latter, *what do you expect*?  It's hard to tell from the intro

Answer (score 1):

Your filter function should return either True or False:

```
def filter_even(N):
    return N % 2 == 0
```

Since it was returning either the number that it got or None, your comparison **f_even(number) != 0** didn't work since **None != 0**.

I changed your code a bit(filtered the values inside the list comprehension):

```
def f_evendecorator(func):
    def get_even(*args):
        f_even = filter_even
        f = func(*args)
        return [i for i in range(1,f + 1) if i%2==0]
    return get_even

@f_evendecorator
def mult(x,y):
    return x * y

print(mult(5,5)) # [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24]
```

Comment: this is what i mean without using outside filter function